# C# shutdown/hibernate/sleep

Tags: c#, sleep, shutdown, restart

Is it possible to shutdown/hibernate/restart/sleep a computer using a C# program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to shutdown/reboot system use -

```
using System.Management;

    void Shutdown()
    {
        ManagementBaseObject mboShutdown = null;
        ManagementClass mcWin32 = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
        mcWin32.Get();

        // You can't shutdown without security privileges
        mcWin32.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        ManagementBaseObject mboShutdownParams =
                 mcWin32.GetMethodParameters("Win32Shutdown");

        // **Flag 1 means we want to shut down the system. Use "2" to reboot**.
        mboShutdownParams["Flags"] = "1";
        mboShutdownParams["Reserved"] = "0";
        foreach (ManagementObject manObj in mcWin32.GetInstances())
        {
            mboShutdown = manObj.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", 
                                           mboShutdownParams, null);
        }
    }
```

[more here](http://www.geekpedia.com/code36_Shut-down-system-using-Csharp.html)

For hibernate and stand by  - If you are using .NET 2.0 you can just call
`Application.SetSuspendState`.

[Check out the documentation at:](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/lib...pendstate.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");  // shutdown
Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /t 0");  // shutdown and restart
Process.Start("shutdown", "/h /f");    // hibernate
```